# Get all slash query string value from current URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have current page URL like this :

> https://example.com/product/view/faqlist/category_id/2/faq/219/

URL will be dynamic. Here, category_id and faq are parameters. I want to get this value.

I tried this below code. But, It's only working when, I just add one query string. It's not working in multiple.

I want to get value of category_id and faq query string's value. How can I do this?

> **Note :** I don't want to change query string from "/" to "?"

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname.split("/");
var filtered_path = pathname.filter(function(v){return v!==''});
var filename = filtered_path[filtered_path.length-1];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `String#split` and the index of the parameters by using `Array#indexOf` can get you the values of the query string values of the URL.

```js
var url = "https://example.com/product/view/faqlist/category_id/2/faq/219/";
var arr = url.split('/');

var a = arr[arr.indexOf('category_id') + 1];
var b = arr[arr.indexOf('faq') + 1];

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: If I want to remove that faq query string, then you know about that code?

Comment: pop the last 2 values from the array you get after splitting and then join it

Comment: Yes. It's static solution. But, for dynamic you know about that? For eg : sometime, I want category_id remove or sometime faq.

Comment: get the index of faq the same way in the above solution. use splice to remove that index and the one after that from array